# "Error: Cannot find module 'internal/util/types'" while installing node packages in a react-redux project

Tags: reactjs, npm, redux, react-redux, npm-install

I am learning Redux and am running into this error anytime I try to install a node package during my initial project setup:

```
`Error: Cannot find module 'internal/util/types'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:31:26
    at Object.<anonymous> 
(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/fs.js:11:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)`
```

I see there are similar threads providing solutions, however none of those solved this problem for me. Two options I have tried:
    1) npm install node v6.2.2 (one thread recommended reverting node version)
    2) npm rebuild

However, any 'npm' command I run simply throws the exact same error. Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Try **npm cache clean --force** and install again. If that doesn't work, try deleting the node_modules folder and run npm install again.

Comment: So my problem is when I try these remedies like npm cache clean --force, the same error occurs. I deleted my node_modules folder, but when I run npm install again the same error occurs. It appears that any command beginning with 'npm' throws this error. I have only been coding for a year, so I am totally unaware of why this is happening. Thanks for your help btw.

Comment: I created a new folder and ran create react app etc. I received the same error message above now with this added to it:                                 `module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^



Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --log level error react react-dom react-scripts@0.9.x has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting todo/ from /Users/bradyjimison/ga/wdi/projects/redux-todo
Done.`